# TabBar back button is not showing in ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have created a UINavigationBarButton where i have placed a button called "update".When update button is clicked it is navigating to SecondViewController.But the problem is in the SecondViewController TabBar is not showing.What I'm trying to do is when i tap the back button in the SecondViewController it should get back to RootViewController.Here is the code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      self.navigationItem.title=@"GooGle";

      [self.navigationItem setLeftItemsSupplementBackButton:YES];
      [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];


      UIBarButtonItem *nextView = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"update" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay target:self action:@selector(updateAddress)];   
      self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nextView;
      [nextView release];  
}

-(void)updateAddress
{
      SecondViewController *updateView=[[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
      [self.navigationController presentViewController:updateView animated:YES completion:Nil];
      [self.navigationItem setLeftItemsSupplementBackButton:YES];
}
```

Comment: once check in SecondViewController class some where else you are hiding that one i think so but not sure.

Comment: Edit your question by providing more information and making it clearer. I cannnot understand what is the problem.

Comment: @Sunny Not hiding any where.And nothing given in SecondViewController.Just pushing RootViewController to SecondViewController

Comment: @pe60t0 The problem is tabbar is not showing in SecondViewController

Comment: Well of course the tabbar won't show. You are presenting SecondViewController modally, which means it wont be inside the tabbar. You have not provided any of the tabbar code in your question, so I cannot give you a proper answer on how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

When you tap the back button in SecondViewController use

```
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Since you are not using

```
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:youViewController animated:YES];
```

the navigationbar won't be visible, if you do so you will have your navigationbar and a back button by its own and while pressing the back button it will itself move to the previous view

share your results

Comment: He is talking about tabbar, not navigationbar

Comment: I guess so, the question is ambiguous

Comment: but any how the tabbarController will be shown if he pushes the controller instead of presenting it as you said in above comment